# Is there a way to turn a witch into a villager?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Once a villager gets struck by lightning and becomes a witch, is it possible to cure it and turn it back into a villager like how you can cure a zombie villager?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it stands now, ***no***. There is no way to reverse a struck witch or a naturally spawned witch into a villager. The [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Witch) specifically says that when a villager is struck it is despawned and a witch is spawned in it's place, only giving the effect of it turning into a witch.

Comment: If this was the case, then why does the villager (previously named librarian) keep his/her assigned name and is turned into a witch?